# Custom Module load JS when all content is loaded in Checkout

Tags: magento2, custom, requirejs

I created a custom module to show suggested addresses when customer type in the address fill. However, the requirejs load before the content of checkout page load, even though I have put "domReady!".

How can I make the script to load after everything is loaded.

**checkout.phtml**

```
<?php
$client_id = $block->getClientID();
$client_secret = $block->getClientSecret();
?>
<?php if ($block->isEnabled()): ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init" order="100">
{
    "*": {
        "addressfinder": {
            "client_id": "<?php echo $client_id; ?>"
        }
    }
}
</script>
<?php endif ?>
```

**addressfinder.js**

```
define([
'jquery',
'domReady!',
'./checkout_mapping'], function($, domReady, data) {
"use strict";
return function(config) {
//my code
}
});
```

Comment: Don't use phtml for that, use knockoutjs style.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `domReady!` is complete when the DOM is ready where as it sounds like you want to target when all the pages assets have loaded.

A quick and dirty way would be to use an event listener for when the window has loaded:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  ...
});
```

But because Magento 2 is terribly slow and downloads hundreds of JS files that will take a while and may result in a slow experience for the users.

A better solution would be to use the same technologies the checkout is built with which means using [UI Components](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html) then you can be sure your components load in the correct order.

Comment: Do you mean by define UI Components in the js file?

Comment: I mean modify the checkout using the same tools it's built with which is UI components consistent of layout XML `<item>`s and Knockout inside HTML templates and Javascript. It's unnecessarily complex but it's usually the cleanest and most performant way to modify the checkout.